# On Windows 7 how do you check to see if a file is a hardlink?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shell, hardlink, mklink

I just created a hardlink in Windows 7 using `mklink`. When I use `dir` the output doesn't indicate that the new hardlink is a hardlink. Instead it looks exactly like the file it is pointing to.

Example output from `dir`:

```
05/16/2013  12:07 AM            40,448 HardlinkToOriginal
05/16/2013  12:07 AM            40,448 OriginalFile
```

On Windows 7 how do you check to see if a file is a hardlink?

I know that you can do: `fsutil.exe hardlink list OriginalFile` and this will tell you that HardlinkToOriginal is a hardlink, but you need a-priori knowledge that is not available. Ideally I would like something like `ls -al` on Linux where if the file is a link then the command tells you it is a link and shows you where it points to.

Comment: I know that you can do: `fsutil.exe hardlink list OriginalFile` and this will tell you that HardlinkToOriginal is a hardlink, but you need a-priori knowledge that is not available. Ideally I would like something like `ls -al` on Linux where if the file is a link then the command tells you it is a link and shows you where it points to.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: http://superuser.com/questions/366739/how-to-find-hard-links-on-windows `find . -links +1`. Additionally I want to mention the tool [ls.exe](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html#contact) which provides the same as `ls` on linux

Comment: Are you sure that `ls -al` *"shows you where it points to"* for *hard* links? (Surely, it does so for symbolic links aka softlinks.)

Comment: @Arjan you are correct. On linux `ls -al` does not show hardlinks. You have to use the solution from the [superuser question here](http://superuser.com/questions/366739/how-to-find-hard-links-on-windows).

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can. In fact, if you delete *OriginalFile*, you'll still have *HardlinkToOriginal* available.

Comment: That is the entire point of using hard links rather than soft links. :)