# How to delete all hardlinks to the same file (inode)?

Tags: windows, shell, filesystems, hardlink, extension

I've used [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) to create a bunch of hardlinks in different directories within the same hard drive (to save space, as I need both stored in different locations). When I want to delete the file permanently the only way I know is to find both hardlinks in my file explorer (win10) and delete both.

Is there a way to delete both hardlinks at the same time with the link shell extension or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm looking for a way to delete those hardlinks from a context menu or similar. Some way as easy as creating hardlinks with the hard link shell extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find hard links on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/366739/how-can-i-find-hard-links-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to delete those hardlinks from a context menu or similar. Some way as easy as creating hardlinks with the hard link shell extension.

Comment: You will always first need to find the actual hard links. Only after that you can delete them. As it seems like that approach is unsuitable for you there probably won't be a solution. Depending on what you're doing you might want to consider using soft links in the future as those will allow you to delete the file. The link itself will be preserved but inaccessible - except if another file is recreated in the old location.

Comment: If you can script the finding and deleting of the links that are not the "real" file using the information in the linked question, you could drop that script into the Send To... folder in Windows and then you'd be able to right-click the file you wish to remove the hardlinks too and select Send To... and Delete Hardlinks.